# Website Slowdown

Tags: sql

I'm seeing a large amount of slowdown on a website I'm working on toward the end of each working day. There seems to be an issue with the database as I'm seeing a large number of connections in the Activity Monitor that seems to be sitting there doing nothing. The Task State is blank which suggests it's a running query but they never seem to disappear. When I run the SQL Profiler I can compare the SPID and see the EventClass is an "ExistingConnection" and the TextData reads:

```
-- network protocol: TCP/IP
set quoted_identifier on
set arithabort off
set numeric_roundabort off
set ansi_warnings on
set ansi_padding on
set ansi_nulls on
set concat_null_yields_null on
set cursor_close_on_commit off
set implicit_transactions off
set language us_english
set dateformat mdy
set datefirst 7
set transaction isolation level read committed
```

This doesn't make a lot of sense to me and there seems to be hundreds of these entries all with different SPID's that never do anything. Any ideas?

Comment: This is not standard SQL.  You should qualify this with the RDBMS you are using and other details.

Answer (score 1):

- A connection doing nothing consumes some memory but not much else
- A connection doing nothing means your app may not be closing them
- The output you give is "Existing connections" in profiler and is run for each connection. It's irrelevant

We need more info. Like what batch jobs or processes or backups or index maintenance is running at the end of each working day?

Comment: There's nothing specific running at the end of each day. But perhaps it's a cumulative effect. If a connections not being closed and sits there I take it it'll get to a point where no connections are left and the app dies?

Answer (score 1):

I'd check web application is using well known connection pooling solution, recheck that it is closing connections (if there is some reason not to use a standard connection pooling solution) and then if there are other users of the database I'd want to know that it is the web application causing the issue, I'm not sure how to test that in your case.  If there was not much data and I did not understand the DB well enough I would set up a dedicated temporary DB to see if the issue continued.  Obviously that would not work in many situations but anything to partition the problem.

Comment: It's not using a well known pooling solution. When the page loads a connection is opened to the database, various queries are run then when the page has finished loading the connection is closed (I inherited this, I didn't write it myself I'd like to add). Problem is the entire site is written this way and I don't currently have the go ahead to change it (It's probably 3 weeks work which I currently don't have)

Comment: ... Tricky... It might not be as bad as you think.  Anyways it depends how the connection is created but a connection pool often improves performance (there is already an open connection to the DB) building a connection every time is wasteful.  Search, replace, test... it wouldn't take that long.  Then you would never have to worry about too many connections there would only be the number of concurrent connections you allow.  If the DB is transactional then you might need to add a start transaction and replace every close with a commit.  But it's not very invasive change.